# Setting axis ticks in cartopy PlateCarree projections with general central longitude

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to set custom longitude axis tick marks and labels on a cartopy plot using a PlateCarree projection (in cartopy 0.20.1). I tried following the answer at [Cartopy: show tick marks of axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465435/cartopy-show-tick-marks-of-axes), but I get funny results when using the set_xticks method for general values of central_longitude in the projection. Is there a way to get specified axis ticks correctly positioned and labelled in general?

```
#With central_longitude=0, it seems to work fine
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

central_longitude=0
fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplot(111,projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=central_longitude))
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_xticks([-90,0,90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

```
#With non-zero central_longitude, the ticks are labelled wrongly, such as below, and sometimes put in the wrong place. 
#Note I thought it may be due to ticks being outside the range of +/- 180 degrees from the central longitude, 
#but there is still a problem when this isn't the case.

central_longitude=45
fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplot(111,projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=central_longitude))
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_xticks([-90,0,90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

I have tried setting central_longitude=45 in ccrs.PlateCarree() on the last line, but this doesn't fix the issue - the ticks are moved to the wrong positions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a colleague for pointing out that using a LongitudeFormatter e.g. by adding the following lines corrects the problem - I had thought that all this did is format the tick label text:

```
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LongitudeFormatter
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
```